# owncloud client does not update in 12.04, asks for partial update

Tags: 12.04, partial-upgrade, owncloud-client

Trying to update with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libocsync-dev libocsync-plugin-owncloud libocsync0
```

I get the following:

```
libocsync-plugin-owncloud : Depends: libocsync0 (= 0.90.4-0) but 0.91.4 is to be installed
```

Any idea how to solve that? I have to stick to 12.04.

Comment: I run the above command and get the following error message: E: Unable to locate package libocsync-plugin-owncloud Now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to solve the problem:

First, completely uninstall owncloud-client

```
sudo apt-get purge libqtkeychain0 libocsync-plugin-owncloud libocsync0 ocsync owncloud-client
```

Then, install again

```
sudo apt-get install owncloud-client
```

Now, no partial upgrade messages anymore.